# I can't Deploy my Ecommerce project to Render (I've tried railway, vercel, fly.io and neither!)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, publish

It is an ecommerce that I have been developing for months and now I encounter this problem when deploying. The Technologies that I am using for the front are Javascript Html and CSS, and for the back JS node express and as DB Google Sheets.

This is my project working perfectly on localhost 3000[image]

To deploy locally you only need an npm install to install the node modules and the rest of the dependencies, and to launch with an npm run start you already have it on port 3000.
The first problem I encounter is that most hosting requests a build command
[image]
and I don't use any npm build start or anything similar. Reason why I indicated the npm install in this section. but when deploying the only thing that is seen on the screen is "Cannot GET /" y el error de consola:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). [image]

I also share an image of my Package.json and what the structure of my project is roughly like:
[image]

index.js:

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
//cargar var de entorno
require('dotenv').config();
//npm install body-parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const repositoryBD = require("./repositoryBD");
const mercadopago = require('mercadopago');

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Agrega credenciales
mercadopago.configure({
    access_token: "TEST-6776565151351351352720-af7c8aaf1e4f5d022b98cb08264a72a9-447474392",
  });

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get('/api/products', async (req, res) => {
  res.send(await repositoryBD.read());
});

app.post('/api/pay', async (req, res) => {
    const order = req.body;
    const productsCopy = await repositoryBD.read();
    const unavailableProducts = [];

    let preference = {
        items: [],
        back_urls: {
            "success": "http://localhost:3000/feedback",
            "failure": "http://localhost:3000/feedback",
            "pending": "http://localhost:3000/feedback"
        },
        auto_return: "approved",
      };

    order.cartProducts.forEach(item => {
        const product = productsCopy.find(p => p.id == item.product.id);// Buscar el producto por ID
        let cantReal = 0
        if (product) {
            cantReal = product.talles[item.talle];
            
            if (cantReal !== undefined && cantReal > 0) {
                
                console.log("cantidad real:"+cantReal+ "cantidad enviada"+ item.cant);
                if(cantReal<item.cant){//verificamos si es factible comprar la cantidad que agregamos y si hay menos enviamos lo que queda de stock en ese talle
                    product.talles[item.talle]-=cantReal;
                    preference.items.push({
                        title: product.name,
                        unit_price: product.price,
                        quantity: parseInt(cantReal),
                    });
                }else{
                    product.talles[item.talle]-=item.cant;
                    preference.items.push({
                        title: product.name,
                        unit_price: product.price,
                        quantity: parseInt(item.cant),
                    });
                }
                
             }else{
                unavailableProducts.push(product.name); // Agregar productos no disponibles a la lista
                console.log("producto no disponible");
            }
        }
    });
    // products = productsCopy;
    // res.send(products);

    if (unavailableProducts.length === 0) {
        const response = await mercadopago.preferences.create(preference)
        const preferenceId = response.body.id;

        await repositoryBD.write(productsCopy);//descontamos del stock
        order.date = new Date().toISOString();
        order.preferenceId = preferenceId;
        order.status = "pending";
        const orders = await repositoryBD.readOrders();//traemos y leemos todas las ordenes que hay en sheet
        order.idOrder = orders[orders.length-1].idOrder + 1;//agregamos el numero de orden(idOrder)
        orders.push(order);//agregamos los datos a la nueva orden
        await repositoryBD.writeOrders(orders);//generamos la orden de compra

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, preferenceId });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Algunos productos no están disponibles', unavailableProducts });
    }
});



app.post('/api/payByTransfer', async (req, res) => {
    const order = req.body;
    const productsCopy = await repositoryBD.read();
    const unavailableProducts = [];

    order.cartProducts.forEach(item => {
        const product = productsCopy.find(p => p.id == item.product.id);// Buscar el producto por ID
        let cantReal = 0
        if (product) {
            cantReal = product.talles[item.talle];

            if (cantReal !== undefined && cantReal > 0) {
                console.log("disponible");
             }else{
                unavailableProducts.push(product.name); // Agregar productos no disponibles a la lista
                console.log("producto no disponible");
            }
        }
    });
    // products = productsCopy;
    // res.send(products);

    if (unavailableProducts.length === 0) {

        await repositoryBD.write(productsCopy);//descontamos del stock
        order.date = new Date().toISOString();
        order.preferenceId = "TRANSFERENCIA";
        order.status = "pending";
        const orders = await repositoryBD.readOrders();//traemos y leemos todas las ordenes que hay en sheet
        order.idOrder = orders[orders.length-1].idOrder + 1;//agregamos el numero de orden(idOrder)
        let orderNumber = order.idOrder; 
        orders.push(order);//agregamos los datos a la nueva orden
        await repositoryBD.writeOrders(orders);//generamos la orden de compra

        res.status(200).json({ success: true, orderNumber });
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Algunos productos no están disponibles', unavailableProducts });
    }
});



app.get('/feedback', async (req, res) => {
    const payment = await mercadopago.payment.findById(req.query.payment_id);
    const merchantOrder = await mercadopago.merchant_orders.findById(payment.body.order.id);
    const preferenceId = merchantOrder.body.preference_id;
    const status = payment.body.status;
    await repositoryBD.updateOrderByPreferenceId(preferenceId,status);

    res.sendFile(require.resolve("./frontend/index.html"))
});

app.use("/",express.static("frontend"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

PACKAGE.JSON:

```
{
  "name": "vionza-ecommerce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Lukezet",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/local-auth": "^2.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "googleapis": "^105.0.0",
    "mercadopago": "^1.5.17"
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance to those willing to help, I have put many hours into this project and it would be a real shame to leave it like this.

Deploy the project on Web

Comment: To start, when you deploy your node backend, do you see the service as being deployed successfully? Can you also confirm the version of node on the server is what you expect it to be? You can find that in the build logs, and you can set it to be whatever you need as an environment variable (see the docs https://render.com/docs/node-version). 
I'll mention too that your node app will be deployed to whatever port you specify, but render only listens to traffic over https (443) and forwards it to the port you defined, so when you call your server, just call the onrender.com URL without a port.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! I've specified the node Version via enviroment variable and when deploy the log message is:
Oct 3 09:21:55 PM  Example app listening on port 10000
Oct 3 09:21:57 PM  Your service is live 
for other side you are tryng to say that i must change this line?
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

Comment: That line is fine I think, I was just trying to say that whatever port you set on your backend isn't where your frontend will call it. The app will listen on 10000, but render can only listen to https, so it will take all the https traffic and send it to port 10000 on your app. So your frontend shouldn't specify any port when it calls your backend service on render.